# SVN: Turn my project folder into a working copy and source version control it

Tags: svn, unity-game-engine, tortoisesvn

This is probably going to be dumb question. I searched and I can't find the answers.

I have an existing unity project. I decided  I want to version control it on my server. So I right click on the project and choose "import repository..". It created the repository successfully. Now When I make change to the files in my project folder, it does not give me the "commit"..etc options of SVN. I read on the website that I need to do "SVN checkout".

However, I have the project folder already, so I dont understand why I need to checkout after importing. Anyways, for the sake of testing, I right clicked on the project folder and I did check out. It ended up duplicating whats on the server inside a newly created folder  inside my project folder. The files in there I can commit and do all stuffs.

However my problem is I  want my existing project folder that I imported to be "my working folder" and not have to create ANOTHER folder to work with since Unity is already based on that folder.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe is pretty simple -- you've specified a wrong path to checkout the working copy to.

Import operation imports the data to the [repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository), but it does not make the imported data a [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) on your machine. That's why you have to checkout a working copy.

You can checkout a working copy atop your existing data and it will make it a working copy that should allow you to commit and perform other version-control operations.

Comment: The last senetence is what I was missing. So basically if I have my project folder (lets call it A). I create a repo of A on the server using import( lets call it B). Then I can go back to A and checkout B "On A" and that would make A my working folder (without the need to check out int new folder called C) .. Correct?